# Keeping files in the webpage until client closes it

Tags: javascript, memory

I have a game which upon loading downloads many files. After I am trying to use them in the webpage they are being downloaded once more, I guess it has something to do with the memory capacity for the webpage but I am having hard time verifying this assumption. What should I do to have files saved in client memory until he closes the webpage? [Here you can see how the same file was downloaded twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU4m8.jpg). First time I use this code to get images from server before playing:

```
function doAjaxImg(param, lambda) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => lambda();
    image.src = param;
}
```

Then I simply change image.src for the image I want to show on the screen and it requests from the server this image again.

Comment: that's what `img.src` does - that's how it works. Assigning a URL (or changing in your case) forces a new request for that resource.

Comment: @RandyCasburn is there any way around that? I want to load files once and use them multiple times throughout the game by changing background-image in an element

Comment: You just need to create a cache for them -> create and `images` array and store each in there. Then, when you need them, pull them from the cache.

Comment: Thank you. I also noted that when I append newly created image to the document and do a request for the same image it doesn't load twice as well.

Comment: It does actually, it just pulling that image from the browser's local cache.